# angularfire collection flatmap of child nodes

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Angular and Google FireStore to store a list of "orders". Each order has a list of "products". How can I get a single observable array of products that is flattened from all "orders" that full-fill our query?

Data looks like this:

```
[
{
  id: "item1",
  products: [
    { product1... }, {product2... }
  ]
},
{
  id: "item2",
  products: [
    { product3...}, {product2... }
  ]
}
]
```

end result should be an observable list of products:

```
[{product1...}, {product2...}, {product3...}, {product2...}]
```

I tried to use flatMap but cannot get it to work correctly with AngularFire query result. My current "try-out" works quite far and it does give out a single list of "products". The problem is that it only has "products" from the last "order".

This is what I have now:

```
return this.db.collection<Order>('orders', ref => ref.where('status', '==', 3))
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    flatMap(orders=> {
      return orders.map(a => {
          const order = a.payload.doc.data() as Order;
          return order.products;
        })}))
```

I know that the schema is awful and "products" should be in it's own collection, but, I have no control over it :(

Please help :)

Comment: If you print on console `orders`  variable in `flatMap` what do you see?

Comment: I see all of the orders. That gives me the impression that "return orders.map()" resets the products "collection" with each orders products instead of appending it.

Comment: You mean you see `[
{
  id: "item1",
  products: [
    { product1..., product2... }
  ]
},
{
  id: "item2",
  products: [
    { product3..., product2... }
  ]
}
]` ?

Comment: Well, I see [{…}, {…}, {…}] in which each object is a DocumentChangeAction<Order> that I turn into actual Order in the map function inside flatMap.

Comment: see my answer - I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `map` rather than `flatMap`?

`flatMap` wants, as parameter, a function which returns an ObservableInput. An array IS and ObservableInput and, in this case, `flatMap` transforms an array in an Observable which emits each item in the array.

Therefore your code

```
flatMap(orders=> {
  return orders.map(a => {
      const order = a.payload.doc.data() as Order;
      return order.products;
    })}))
```

returns an Observable which emits each item of the `orders` collection as a separate notification.

If you want an Observable which emits a list of products, i.e. which emits an array, than you can substitute `flatMap` with `map`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it gives me an array of arrays filled with products. eg. [ [ {...},{...},{...} ], [ {...},{...},{...} ] ], what I am after should be like this [ {...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...} ]. So, that is why I thought of flatMap ... How can I "flatten" the result inside of my stream?

Comment: I would use the `reduce` method of Array

Comment: I have added one more answer to show how to use `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to use `reduce`.

```
const myArrayOfArrays = [
  [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}, {id: 3, name: 'c'}],
  [{id: 10, name: 'x'}, {id: 20, name: 'y'}, {id: 30, name: 'z'}],
  [{id: 100, name: 'ax'}, {id: 200, name: 'by'}, {id: 300, name: 'cz'}],
]
of(myArrayOfArrays).pipe(
  map(myArrayOfArrays => myArrayOfArrays
    .reduce(
      (acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []
    ))
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

without using flatMap (and pipe), try this:

```
  return this.db.collection<Order>('orders', ref => 
                ref.where('status', '==', 3))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .map(orders => {
           return orders.map(a => {
                  const order = a.payload.doc.data() as Order;
                 return order;
                 });
           })
        .mergeMap(p => from(p.products));
```

Comment: I think the pipe is needed with recent rxjs versions. Your solution outputs the products from the last order, not all products from all orders. Thank you for your effort anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your time and effort, I truly appreciate it.

This is what I ended up with, sadly it does not "feel" correct but, it works.

```
flatMap(orders=> {
 let products = [];
 orders.map(a => {
  const order = a.payload.doc.data() as Order;
  order.products.map(product => products.push(product));
 })
 return of(products);
}))
```